# Supports unicode for filenames in archives wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I need unpack an archive which contains unicode characters for filenames in archives.

My code equivalent this:

```
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include <wx/archive.h>
#include <wx/wfstream.h>
#include <wx/zipstrm.h>
#include <wx/fs_arc.h>
#include "wx/fs_zip.h"
#include <memory>
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title) :
        wxFrame( NULL, -1, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(350,180 ),
                 wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wxRESIZE_BORDER | wxMAXIMIZE_BOX))
    {
        wxBoxSizer* Sizer = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );
        TextBox = new wxTextCtrl( this, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTE_MULTILINE );
        Sizer->Add( TextBox, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxEXPAND, 5 );
        auto Button = new wxButton( this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Show entries"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
        Button->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, [this](wxCommandEvent&)
        {
            auto filename = "test.zip";
            auto factory = wxArchiveClassFactory::Find(filename, wxSTREAM_FILEEXT);
            if(!factory)
                return;
            std::unique_ptr<wxArchiveInputStream> inarc(factory->NewStream(new wxFFileInputStream(filename)));
            std::unique_ptr<wxArchiveEntry> entry(factory->NewEntry());
            while (entry.reset(inarc->GetNextEntry()), entry.get() != NULL)
                TextBox->AppendText("Entry :  "+entry->GetName()+"\n");

        });
        Sizer->Add( Button, 0, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 );
        this->SetSizer( Sizer );
        this->Layout();
    }
private:
    wxTextCtrl* TextBox;
};

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit() wxOVERRIDE
    {
        MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame(wxT("Test"));
        frame->Show(true);
        return true;
    };
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

Is it possible to get the correct names for these files using wxWidgets?

Edit: I on Windows7 use wxWidgets 3.1.0, compiler - cl( 17.00.50727.1) VS11.

Comment: what is you wx version, OS version, toolkit name and version and compiler? Can you reproduce it in the archive sample? Can you try this with the Git HEAD if its reproducible? Also, I think there is a unit test for this...

Comment: @Igor, I added version for library and compiler. And I can not found samples and unit test for it also as and get current version from git.

Comment: you need to install cppunit and build the wxWidgets UT suite. There is a wxWidgets/tests/archive/ziptest.cpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you suffer this bug: http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/17244 which has been fixed *after* wx3.1 release.

You need to download the current head code (available with git).